# UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance not present in info.pList ios

Tags: ios

"UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance" is missing in info.pList file. I can't found this in my pList file.Please help me to find this.

Comment: Have you tried adding **View controller-based status bar appearance** in the info.plist?

Comment: Do you really need it set to false? [When this key is not present or its value is set to YES…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35838650/uiviewcontrollerbasedstatusbarappearance-not-present-in-info-plist-ios)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can open `.plist` file as `Source Code` then add this line inside `<dict>` tag

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <true/>
```

Comment: NOTE: The only known use case would be to set it to `<false/>`